# Copying an Excel table (with pictures) to PowerPoint as an image shifts the pictures

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am attempting to make a spreadsheet that will bulk create (approx 450) PowerPoints files containing randomly selected sets of questions and their answers for my science class.

To do this, for each PowerPoint, I create two tables in Excel, a questions table and an answers table, which will go on two separate slides. The right-most column of the questions table includes a picture for each question to help support weaker learners, which can be hidden/displayed on the PowerPoint slides using a system of shapes, animations and triggers. Both tables can include subscript and superscript formatting as scientific conventions often need these.

The formatting and sizing of everything is extremely important to ensure that the images line-up properly with the questions, and to ensure that when they are pasted into the PowerPoint slides, the hiding/displaying of the pictures works properly.

My tables look perfect in Excel, but the problems begin when tying to get them into PowerPoint...

**Option one:**
Paste tables into PowerPoint as an image using the below:

```
ws3.Range("Indirect(B63)").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture 'The specified range is the question table
StarterPres.Slides(2).Shapes.PasteSpecial 'StarterPres is the PowerPoint
```

However, what looks like this in Excel, [(images properly aligned in the third table column)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BRyX.png) appears like this when pasted
[(images translated left by a random amount)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsJNR.png).
The offsetting of the images is always towards the left and the amount varies from a few mm to several cm (this is a particularly extreme example). This also happens when I manually select the range by mouse and paste it as image into the PowerPoint, interestingly, when I do this, even if I just select the cells containing the questions (and not their pictures), the translated images also appear.

Is this an insurmountable bug in the way VBA handles images or is there some kind of parameter that is somehow getting screwed up but could be reset?

**Option 2:**
Paste the table into PowerPoint as a table. However, this very quickly gets more fiddly than my understanding of PwerPoint and VBA can handle:

- The pictures don't copy across so they have to be copied separately, and each image needs to be individually relocated.
- Formatting issues between Excel and PowerPoint cause the height of some of the table rows to change, which means that it is difficult to know exactly what to set as the horizontal alignment for each of the pictures, and some pictures then need resizing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am close to curling up in the corner and having a little cry!

Comment: I have tested `Option1` on Office 365 w/o any issue. What's "Indirect(B63)"? It is invalid as a table name or a defined name. If cell B63 keeps the table name or reference name, you should use `ws3.Range(ws.Range(Indirect(B63)))` .

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. 'ws3.Range("Indirect(B63)")' is just a dynamically named range, in this case it refers to "BJ1:BM8". I don't think the issue is directly due to my code because a) The issue does not always happen, b) When it does happen, it is by different amounts each time and c) doing the same Copy-Paste-As-Image manually also seems to occasionally produce the same issue (but only when I have previously run my code).

Comment: It's a typo in my comment. It could be `you should use ws3.Range(ws.Range("B63"))`. I have tested copy-paste by manual or with code. I haven't seen any issures. Hope others can reproduce your case..

Comment: A completely different approach: instead of storing the images in Excel, you could store the file path (ie, c:\somefolder\imagename.png) and have PPT insert the picture that you could reposition and resize directly. If you do this, there's another little trick that will allow you to preserve animations: add a rectangle to your example slide and animate it. Then instead of inserting an image, set the rectangle's fill to the image you want. The animation will remain untouched. The only hitch is that the rectangle must be in the same proportions as the image, or the image will get distorted.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thanks, this is a good idea, but will be quite a major restructuring so will be my approach oflast-resort. My current plan is to attempt to take screenshots and resizie them once in PowerPoint. Wish me luck!